# Setter para un array

Tags: java, array

el caso es que se me ha planteado una duda respecto a los arrays y los setters. Si yo creo un array dentro de una clase y desde la clase main quiero llamar al método setter de ese array, no funciona como yo esperaría:

```
clase1.setNombresArray("Carlos Mendoza", "Julio Maldonado", "Enrique Pajares", "Diego Blanco", "María del Rosal");
```

Y mi setter es el siguiente:

```
public void setNombresArray(String[] nombres) {
    this.nombres = nombres;
}
```

¿Entonces cómo puedo hacer para que desde la clase main pueda introducir 5 nombres al array de longitud 5?¿Debo hacer un bucle en el que se van pasando los nombres uno a uno?

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tu método recibe un array no 5 variables de tipo String....debes ingresar los nombres en el array y despues pasarlo como parametro en tu metodo

```
String[]nombre={"Carlos Mendoza", "Julio Maldonado", "Enrique Pajares", "Diego Blanco", "María del Rosal"};

clase1.setNombresArray(nombre);
```

si sabes la cantidad de nombres que vas a ingresar,usarias un bucle para llenar el array y luego hacer uso del setter, caso contrario lo mejor es usar un `ArrayList`

Comment: Eso es, ahora me siento tonto xD. Muchas gracias!!